# Error while installing lamp-server or any other server on my ubuntu 16.04LTS

Tags: apt, dpkg, sudo, lamp

When i try to install lamp-server by entering command :

```
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
```

I get the following output on my terminal :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libhttp-message-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libencode-locale-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'php7.0-cli' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'mysql-client-5.7' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libapache2-mod-php' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'rename' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-5.7' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'php-common' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libaprutil1' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'php7.0-opcache' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libcgi-fast-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libwrap0' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libhttp-date-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'perl-modules-5.22' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'liblwp-mediatypes-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libfcgi-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libcgi-pm-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'php7.0-common' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libaio1' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libio-html-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'ssl-cert' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'apache2-data' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libperl5.22' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libapr1' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libaprutil1-ldap' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libhtml-tagset-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'mysql-client-core-5.7' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'php7.0-json' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'php7.0-readline' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'tcpd' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'liblua5.1-0' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'mysql-common' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libhtml-template-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libtimedate-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'apache2-bin' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'apache2' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'php-mysql' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'apache2-utils' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libhtml-parser-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libapache2-mod-php7.0' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'liburi-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-core-5.7' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'php7.0-mysql' for task 'lamp-server'
libaio1 is already the newest version (0.3.110-2).
libapr1 is already the newest version (1.5.2-3).
libaprutil1 is already the newest version (1.5.4-1build1).
libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 is already the newest version (1.5.4-1build1).
libaprutil1-ldap is already the newest version (1.5.4-1build1).
libcgi-fast-perl is already the newest version (1:2.10-1).
libcgi-pm-perl is already the newest version (4.26-1).
libencode-locale-perl is already the newest version (1.05-1).
libfcgi-perl is already the newest version (0.77-1build1).
libhtml-parser-perl is already the newest version (3.72-1).
libhtml-tagset-perl is already the newest version (3.20-2).
libhtml-template-perl is already the newest version (2.95-2).
libhttp-date-perl is already the newest version (6.02-1).
libhttp-message-perl is already the newest version (6.11-1).
libio-html-perl is already the newest version (1.001-1).
liblua5.1-0 is already the newest version (5.1.5-8ubuntu1).
liblwp-mediatypes-perl is already the newest version (6.02-1).
libtimedate-perl is already the newest version (2.3000-2).
liburi-perl is already the newest version (1.71-1).
libwrap0 is already the newest version (7.6.q-25).
rename is already the newest version (0.20-4).
ssl-cert is already the newest version (1.0.37).
tcpd is already the newest version (7.6.q-25).
apache2 is already the newest version (2.4.18-2ubuntu3.5).
apache2-bin is already the newest version (2.4.18-2ubuntu3.5).
apache2-data is already the newest version (2.4.18-2ubuntu3.5).
apache2-utils is already the newest version (2.4.18-2ubuntu3.5).
libapache2-mod-php is already the newest version (1:7.0+35ubuntu6.1).
libapache2-mod-php7.0 is already the newest version (7.0.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.1).
libperl5.22 is already the newest version (5.22.1-9ubuntu0.2).
mysql-client-5.7 is already the newest version (5.7.21-0ubuntu0.16.04.1).
mysql-client-core-5.7 is already the newest version (5.7.21-0ubuntu0.16.04.1).
mysql-common is already the newest version (5.7.21-0ubuntu0.16.04.1).
mysql-server is already the newest version (5.7.21-0ubuntu0.16.04.1).
mysql-server-core-5.7 is already the newest version (5.7.21-0ubuntu0.16.04.1).
perl is already the newest version (5.22.1-9ubuntu0.2).
perl-modules-5.22 is already the newest version (5.22.1-9ubuntu0.2).
php-common is already the newest version (1:35ubuntu6.1).
php-mysql is already the newest version (1:7.0+35ubuntu6.1).
php7.0-cli is already the newest version (7.0.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.1).
php7.0-common is already the newest version (7.0.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.1).
php7.0-json is already the newest version (7.0.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.1).
php7.0-mysql is already the newest version (7.0.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.1).
php7.0-opcache is already the newest version (7.0.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.1).
php7.0-readline is already the newest version (7.0.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libappindicator1 libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libindicator7
  libmysqlclient20 libreadline5 libterm-readkey-perl mariadb-common
  python-appindicator python-gconf python-gobject python-pexpect
  python-ptyprocess
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
Suggested packages:
  mailx tinyca
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mysql-server-5.7
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
7 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/2,724 kB of archives.
After this operation, 48.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 289162 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-5.7_5.7.21-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Aborting downgrade from (at least) 10.0 to 5.7.
    If are sure you want to downgrade to 5.7, remove the file
/var/lib/mysql/debian-*.flag and try installing again.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.7_5.7.21-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.7_5.7.21-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

When I run apt-get update :

```
Fetched 306 kB in 13s (22.6 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Fetched 306 kB in 13s (22.6 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

This is maybe because the "http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages" is not online, i guess. But how to solve this error, please help me out here.

Previously, I had a similar error with qbittorrent, and what i did was i opened software-properties-gtk and unticked its repository in the "other softwares" tab. But i have been told it is a bad practice to do so, so do i tick that option again, and how to change those websites?

Comment: You have two unrelated problems. Your `mysql` server is not yet installed; see to that first. Then solve the `pinta` problem. What happens if you install `mysql`manually with `sudo apt install mysql-server-5.7`?

Comment: E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Please add the full error message to the question.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1024263/mysql-server-installation-not-completed-please-help-really-important 

@Jos