# MySQL-server installation does not complete

Tags: apt, mysql

When I run the command, `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`, I get the following errors...

```
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libevent-core-2.0-5 mysql-client-5.7 mysql-common mysql-server-5.7
Suggested packages:
  mailx tinyca
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libevent-core-2.0-5 mysql-client-5.7 mysql-common mysql-server
  mysql-server-5.7
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/4,497 kB of archives.
After this operation, 82.9 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-common.
(Reading database ... 288832 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-common_5.7.21-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-common (5.7.21-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-client-5.7.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-client-5.7_5.7.21-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-client-5.7 (5.7.21-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libevent-core-2.0-5:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libevent-core-2.0-5_2.0.21-stable-2ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libevent-core-2.0-5:amd64 (2.0.21-stable-2ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
Setting up mysql-common (5.7.21-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-5.7.
(Reading database ... 288884 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-5.7_5.7.21-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.21-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server_5.7.21-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server (5.7.21-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu21.2) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up mysql-client-5.7 (5.7.21-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up libevent-core-2.0-5:amd64 (2.0.21-stable-2ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.21-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
mysql_upgrade: Got error: 1524: Plugin 'unix_socket' is not loaded while connecting to the MySQL server
Upgrade process encountered error and will not continue.
mysql_upgrade failed with exit status 11
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                      Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu21.2) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I read through a lot of forums and websites before posting here. The list of things I have already tried :

1. [Ubuntu 15.10 mysql error 1524 - unix_socket | Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/705458/ubuntu-15-10-mysql-error-1524-unix-socket)
2. Changed the `my.conf` file
3. purged `mysql-*` files, reinstalled them
4. [Configure MySQL server on Ubuntu | rackspace.com](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/configuring-mysql-server-on-ubuntu/)

I am really stuck so it would be immensely helpful if someone guided me a way out of this.

Comment: Did you have installed mariadb-server before you try install mysql-server? Do you have any databases in this MySQL instance or it is the clear (new) installation?

Comment: It is a new installation with no database, and yes i did install maria-db before mysql-server @mariaczi

Answer (score 4):

I finally was able to solve the problem by removing all the dependencies and configuration files of the mysql as well as maria-db first. To do that, go to `/var/lib` and delete all the files related to mysql (You will have to have root permissions to delete them so dont forget to write `sudo su` before that). You can delete all the files by typing `rm -r /var/lib/mysql*`.
After that you have to delete all the files in the /etc directory by typing `rm -r /etc/mysql*`

Then perform the following commands and you will be set to go :

```
sudo apt purge mysql-client-5.7 mysql-client-core-5.7 mysql-common mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server-core-5.7 mysql-server
sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade && sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt -f install
sudo apt install mysql-server
```

Comment: thanks you - this is most helpful. Wrestled with this for too long today.

Comment: I hope people stumble on this answer sooner than I did. Finally finally able to setup sql server on my system.

Answer (score 1):

Try these. Hope it helps.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql*
sudo apt-get purge mysql* 
sudo apt-get autoremove 
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get remove dbconfig-mysql
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Comment: Still the same error persists.. as in the question

Comment: My solution is the same thing as you've written as an answer..

Comment: `mysql*` means all the packages in your system which name starts with `mysql`

Comment: I tried that, it did not delete the config files and the dependencies in /var/lib as well as etc/mysql @surjit