# MySQL Server 5.7 not installing correctly

Tags: 16.04, server, mysql

I am receiving the following message when trying to install MySQL Server 5.7 on a server after updating to Ubuntu 16.04.1. Doe anyone know how I can correct this?

```
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2018-05-17 17:03:09 UTC; 7ms ago
  Process: 7392 ExecStartPost=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 7391 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=2)
  Process: 7382 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 7391 (code=exited, status=2)

May 17 17:03:09 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
May 17 17:03:09 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
May 17 17:03:09 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

journalctl -xe shows this:

```
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: It is possible that mysqld could use up to
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 68195 K  bytes of memory
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: Thread pointer: 0x0
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: terribly wrong...
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x40000
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x3b)[0xe907ab]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x489)[0x789b49]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x11390)[0x7ff8de0a8390]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x38)[0x7ff8dd461428]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x16a)[0x7ff8dd46302a]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld[0x75f3e0]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN2ib5fatalD1Ev+0x145)[0x1128eb5]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z20buf_page_io_completeP10buf_page_tb+0x3b4)[0x1167514]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z13buf_read_pageRK9page_id_tRK11page_size_t+0x4e2)[0x1199412]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z16buf_page_get_genRK9page_id_tRK11page_size_tmP11buf_block_tmPKcmP5mtr_tb+0x4f1)[0x1165b71]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld[0xfc2696]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z29ibuf_merge_or_delete_for_pageP11buf_block_tRK9page_id_tPK11page_size_tm+0x7e0)[0xfcc0b0]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z20buf_page_io_completeP10buf_page_tb+0x460)[0x11675c0]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z13buf_read_pageRK9page_id_tRK11page_size_t+0x4e2)[0x1199412]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z16buf_page_get_genRK9page_id_tRK11page_size_tmP11buf_block_tmPKcmP5mtr_tb+0x4f1)[0x1165b71]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld[0x11eac06]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z14fseg_free_stepPhbP5mtr_t+0x18d)[0x11ef85d]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld[0x113a16e]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z18btr_free_if_existsRK9page_id_tRK11page_size_tmP5mtr_t+0x8a)[0x113a44a]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z20dict_drop_index_treePhP10btr_pcur_tP5mtr_t+0x131)[0x119e221]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld[0x10b0982]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z7row_updP10upd_node_tP9que_thr_t+0x6b)[0x10b243b]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z12row_upd_stepP9que_thr_t+0x8b)[0x10b26eb]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z15que_run_threadsP9que_thr_t+0x7e5)[0x103a065]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z12que_eval_sqlP11pars_info_tPKcmP5trx_t+0x94)[0x103ac04]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z24row_drop_table_for_mysqlPKcP5trx_tbbP12dict_table_t+0xa34)[0x107bbe4]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld[0x1211ab8]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld[0x1213f3f]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z24fts_drop_orphaned_tablesv+0x6ce)[0x121472e]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z29recv_recovery_rollback_activev+0x33)[0xfee763]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z34innobase_start_or_create_for_mysqlv+0x5195)[0x10d1eb5]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld[0xf91f5f]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z24ha_initialize_handlertonP13st_plugin_int+0x51)[0x7d7291]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld[0xc706c5]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z40plugin_register_builtin_and_init_core_sePiPPc+0x318)[0xc73ae8]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld[0x781f5f]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11mysqld_mainiPPc+0xa49)[0x783949]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7ff8dd44c830]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_start+0x29)[0x779de9]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
May 17 17:21:21 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
lines 986-1035/1035 (END)
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: It is possible that mysqld could use up to
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 68195 K  bytes of memory
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: Thread pointer: 0x0
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: terribly wrong...
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x40000
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x3b)[0xe907ab]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x489)[0x789b49]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x11390)[0x7ff8de0a8390]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x38)[0x7ff8dd461428]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x16a)[0x7ff8dd46302a]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld[0x75f3e0]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN2ib5fatalD1Ev+0x145)[0x1128eb5]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z20buf_page_io_completeP10buf_page_tb+0x3b4)[0x1167514]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z13buf_read_pageRK9page_id_tRK11page_size_t+0x4e2)[0x1199412]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z16buf_page_get_genRK9page_id_tRK11page_size_tmP11buf_block_tmPKcmP5mtr_tb+0x4f1)[0x1165b71]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld[0xfc2696]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z29ibuf_merge_or_delete_for_pageP11buf_block_tRK9page_id_tPK11page_size_tm+0x7e0)[0xfcc0b0]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z20buf_page_io_completeP10buf_page_tb+0x460)[0x11675c0]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z13buf_read_pageRK9page_id_tRK11page_size_t+0x4e2)[0x1199412]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z16buf_page_get_genRK9page_id_tRK11page_size_tmP11buf_block_tmPKcmP5mtr_tb+0x4f1)[0x1165b71]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld[0x11eac06]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z14fseg_free_stepPhbP5mtr_t+0x18d)[0x11ef85d]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld[0x113a16e]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z18btr_free_if_existsRK9page_id_tRK11page_size_tmP5mtr_t+0x8a)[0x113a44a]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z20dict_drop_index_treePhP10btr_pcur_tP5mtr_t+0x131)[0x119e221]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld[0x10b0982]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z7row_updP10upd_node_tP9que_thr_t+0x6b)[0x10b243b]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z12row_upd_stepP9que_thr_t+0x8b)[0x10b26eb]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z15que_run_threadsP9que_thr_t+0x7e5)[0x103a065]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z12que_eval_sqlP11pars_info_tPKcmP5trx_t+0x94)[0x103ac04]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z24row_drop_table_for_mysqlPKcP5trx_tbbP12dict_table_t+0xa34)[0x107bbe4]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld[0x1211ab8]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld[0x1213f3f]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z24fts_drop_orphaned_tablesv+0x6ce)[0x121472e]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z29recv_recovery_rollback_activev+0x33)[0xfee763]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z34innobase_start_or_create_for_mysqlv+0x5195)[0x10d1eb5]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld[0xf91f5f]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z24ha_initialize_handlertonP13st_plugin_int+0x51)[0x7d7291]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld[0xc706c5]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z40plugin_register_builtin_and_init_core_sePiPPc+0x318)[0xc73ae8]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld[0x781f5f]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11mysqld_mainiPPc+0xa49)[0x783949]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7ff8dd44c830]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_start+0x29)[0x779de9]
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
May 17 17:21:21 mysqld[10831]: information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
May 17 17:21:21 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
```

systemctl status mysql.service shows this:

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (start-post) (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2018-05-17 17:25:21 UTC; 26s ago
  Process: 11554 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=2)
  Process: 11545 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 11554 (code=exited, status=2);         : 11555 (mysql-systemd-s)
    Tasks: 2
   Memory: 312.0K
      CPU: 2.152s
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
           └─control
             ├─11555 /bin/bash /usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post
             └─11625 sleep 1

May 17 17:25:23 mysqld[11554]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z24ha_initialize_handlertonP13st_plugin_int+0x51)[0x7d7291]
May 17 17:25:23 mysqld[11554]: /usr/sbin/mysqld[0xc706c5]
May 17 17:25:23 mysqld[11554]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z40plugin_register_builtin_and_init_core_sePiPPc+0x318)[0xc73ae8]
May 17 17:25:23 mysqld[11554]: /usr/sbin/mysqld[0x781f5f]
May 17 17:25:23 mysqld[11554]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11mysqld_mainiPPc+0xa49)[0x783949]
May 17 17:25:23 mysqld[11554]: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7f30c2384830]
May 17 17:25:23 mysqld[11554]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_start+0x29)[0x779de9]
May 17 17:25:23 mysqld[11554]: The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
May 17 17:25:23 mysqld[11554]: information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
May 17 17:25:23 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After googling I did find the answer, the solution was to first remove all MySQL files from /var/lib/ and /etc/, then do a clean install. Full solution at the link.

https://askubuntu.com/a/1024310/831153